# Vue plugin - Vue is defined but never used

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to install a Vue plugin, so that I can manage some API calls with options. I have a **stocks.js** file, from which I would like to make my API calls.

When I do the following, I get a **'Vue is defined but never used'** error.

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const MyPlugin = {
  install(Vue) {
    Vue.myAddedMethod = function() {
      return **API Call Here**
    }
  }
};

export default MyPlugin;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in the [official guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin), your plugin does not need to require Vue.

Instead, it must be exported and must have an install function.